# Dynamic text, CSS and hanging punctuation using AS3

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flash

Having a problem getting hanging indents to work properly. Can anyone suggest what is incorrect in the following?

```
import flash.text.*;

var styles = new flash.text.StyleSheet();
styles.setStyle("p", {letterSpacing:-9});
styles.setStyle(".indent", {color: '#010000', textIndent: '-20px'} );


headline.styleSheet = styles;

headline.htmlText='<p>FIRST LINE<br>2ND LINE<br>3RD LINE,<br><span class="indent">\"4TH LINE HANGING PUNCTUATION</span>\"<br>5TH LINE </p>';
```

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean by "hanging punctuation" but text-indent will not (and should not) work with span, you need to set it on the p tag. *The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `display:block` for `.indent`